# Troubleshooting persistent periodic high ping

Tags: network, wifi, ping

Using `gping` to plot the ping to three different targets - one on my LAN, google.com and cloudflare.com produces the following plot. Notice the repeating pattern of high peaks in an otherwise low latency streak. It almost looks like three different processes, which occur at the same period. It is very persistent over time and even over several networks. It seems highly isolated to my machine, as other macs on the same network do not show this behavior. I am unsure how to proceed troubleshooting this. How can I find out what's happening here?
[image: three plots showing ping to different targets. a pattern of periodic peaks is shown in all three pings, indicating the error is the source rather than the target.]

Comment: Try the same test suite on a temporary non-admin user account on your Mac to see if it is some background process running under _your_ user account. Is your Mac connected to a NAS device? Are you connected to cloud servers (GDrive, Dropbox, etc?)

Comment: Issue persists in another user. It is connected to a few cloud servers, but I tried my best to turn them all off (and any weird helpers i found in Activity Monitor) but the problem persists regardless. No NAS.

Comment: Tear down (forget) the existing WiFI network on your Mac and rebuild it. What DNS servers does your Mac look to? If you have an Ethernet port on your router (and an Ethernet port on your Mac) turn off WiFi and see if the problem surfaces on the wire. (You don't say if you are using a desktop or laptop Mac.)

Comment: It persists on different networks. It is completely removed using ethernet (on mbp for the record, via usb c dongle). Seems to be related to the wifi on this machine. I tried with the built in router DNS and 8.8.8.8.